# List all aliases available in fish/bash shell

Tags: bash, macos, shell, alias, fish

Is there a way to list all aliases, something like:

```
$ ls-aliases
.. "cd .."
la "ls -Gla"
gs "git stash"
etc...
```

Also is it possible to add human readable descriptions to aliases ?

I'm on a MacOSX

Comment: See: `help alias`

Comment: If your alias is complex enough to need a comment or description, it should probably be a function instead.

Comment: `fish` and `bash` are two different shells, from completely different families with no pretense or attempt at mutual compatibility. Asking for both in the same question is questionable -- it'd be like asking how to do the same thing in LISP and C.

Comment: (Moreover, questions about interactive use belong on [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), not Stack Overflow -- per https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, only questions "unique to software development" are topical here; and aliases aren't even enabled in scripts at all!)

Answer (score 33):

In `bash`:

To list all aliases:

```
alias
```

To add a comment, just put it at the end of the command, e.g.:

```
$ alias foo='echo bar #some description'

$ foo
bar

$ alias foo
alias foo='echo bar #some description'
```

Comment: Is this for bash or fish?

Comment: @JamesK `bash`, clarified.

Comment: `alias` didn't work in fish but `functions` does, although not very readable. `-, ., .., ..., D, N_, abbr, alias, aliases, c, cd, cleanup, cnpm, contains_seq, d`, `functions | sort -u` helps but doesn't have descriptions/command

Answer (score 12):

If someone stumbles upon this like I did:

Current `fish` version (3.0.2) has `alias` (without params) that lists all aliases.

(Similarly `abbr` lists all abbreviations.)

(@heemayl pointed out that `bash` has `alias` as well...)

Answer (score 8):

Note that in fish the `alias` command creates a function using the alias name that wraps the alias value. So there isn't currently any way to list just "aliases". You can use the `functions` command to list the names of all the defined functions (which by definition includes aliases). If you want the names one per line just `functions | cat`.

Comment: If you want to show the implementation of all the funtions, do `type (functions)`

Answer (score 4):

You can add your own fish function to list aliases like so:

```
$ function aliases --description "list all fish aliases"          0|19:02:45
      for f in (functions)
          functions $f | grep \'alias
      end
  end
```

Then save it

```
$ funcsave aliases
```

And call it

```
$ aliases
```

Example output:

```
function fishc --description 'alias fishc=vim ~/.config/fish/config.fish' 
function flutter --description 'alias flutter=~/Repos/DevResources/flutter/bin/flutter' 
function imgcat --description 'alias imgcat=~/.iterm2/imgcat' 
function imgls --description 'alias imgls=~/.iterm2/imgls' 
function inkscape --description 'alias inkscape=/usr/local/Cellar/inkscape/0.92.2_1/bin/inkscape'
```

Comment: This is not needed with the `functions` builtin.  Not sure what version it arrived.

Answer (score 1):

**Fish:**

```
⏵ functions
abbr, ack, acs, alias, calc, cd…

⏵ functions ls
function ls
    command ls -A -x --si --color --classify --group-directories-first $argv;
end
```