# Get all aliases in Linux shell

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

How to list all aliases defined in a shell?

Like the command below to list all files/folders in a directory.

I have defined some aliases in `~/.bashrc` that I want to list.

```bash
ls in a directory
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List all aliases available in fish/bash shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39942004/list-all-aliases-available-in-fish-bash-shell)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Are you wondering if you have a UNIX alias already set for a specific command?

You can find it easily by issuing this on the command line:

```
alias
```

This command will list all aliases currently set for your shell session.

Answer (score 12):

Just type `alias` in terminal?
This should give you all active aliases.

For example:

```
$alias
alias ..='cd ..'
alias ...='cd ../..'
alias ga='git add'
alias gc='git commit'
alias gitlg='git log --graph --pretty=format:'\''%Cred%h%Creset -
%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset'\'' --abbrev-
commit'
alias gs='git st'
alias ll='ls -l'
alias ls='ls -F --color=auto --show-control-chars'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `compgen` command as follows:

```bash
compgen -a
```

- `compgen` empowers you to list all your defined aliases, functions and commands.

Another option would be `alias` command itself.

```bash
alias
```